# Change slideshow to autoplay

Tags: jquery, slideshow, autoplay

Im very new to JQuery and have a simple question.  I found this simple slideshow online but would like to have the slideshow autopaly and remove the checkbox button. Can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Basically the slideshow will autoplay when "checkbox" is selected.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you only want slideshow to autoplay without having to click checkbox...
If that is the case just put this code:

```
setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
}, 3000);
```

Out of $("#checkbox").click function.

Here is complete code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
}, 3000);

var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

$('a.control_prev').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
});

$('a.control_next').click(function () {
    moveRight();
});
});
```

Now just remove checkbox element and slider will automatically autoplay...

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code of:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {



    $('#checkbox').change(function(){
        setInterval(function () {
            moveRight();
        }, 3000);
      });
```

With the following code:

```
$('#slider').ready(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });
```

This change worked for me. Good Luck.